# How can i affix acces token to the request (Laravel passport)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.5, laravel-passport

I have an application with Laravel Passport. Firstly i created new access token with postman ( look at screen)

http://joxi.ru/nAynW7asYJGqzr

Secondly i protected my api routes with auth:api middleware

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function(){

    Route::get('/prepare/', 'CompgenApiController@prepareDefault');

    Route::post('/replace/', 'CompgenApiController@replaceImage');

    Route::get('/replaceall/', 'CompgenApiController@replaceAllImages');

    Route::get('/collage/', 'CompgenApiController@collage');

    Route::get('/generate/', 'CompgenApiController@generate');

    Route::post('/upload/', 'CompgenApiController@userUpload');

    Route::post('/reupload/', 'CompgenApiController@moderationReupload');

    Route::post('/feedback/', 'CompgenApiController@feedback');

});
```

Now i can use my api routes with postman and bots. But now i can`t use this routes with my VueJs if I am not authorized.

what should I do to users could use this api but without authorized? I think i can affix token to the vuejs-request. Or may be i have to create new token with 'Laravel Personal Access Client' ?

Comment: did you follow any doc/tutorial [like this](https://medium.com/carbono/laravel-api-vue-spa-authentication-354dbd9ef1b0)

Comment: no, but i saw this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Comment: Why are you protecting routes that don't require authorisation? Surely, you just want to remove the `auth:api` middleware for routes that are publicly accessible.

Comment: Then please share your try and error if any ?

Comment: I have to protect my api ruotes with passport but i also have to ignore middleware 'auth' with my vuejs requests